# Find all symlinks but tell which are to files and which to directories

Tags: symlink

I want to find all the symlinks in a directory structure, and be able to tell the difference between which are links to files and which to directories.

This command does everything I need except telling me which links are to directories and which are to files.

```bash
find . -type l -ls
```

Comment: I should have said I am using LINUX.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to find which files are **regular files** and which ones are **directories**.

So you can use something like this:

**Solution 1**

```bash
find -type l -exec stat -L --printf '%n is a %F\n' {} +
```

*If you had symbolic links to named pipes or any other type of file the command above will print them too.*

**Ignoring broken links:**

```bash
find -type l ! -xtype l -exec stat -L --printf '%n is a %F\n' {} +
#or
find -type l -not -xtype l -exec stat -L --printf '%n is a %F\n' {} +
#Or
find -type l -readable  -exec stat -L --printf '%n is a %F\n' {} +
```

The `stat -L` is used to follow links while `%n` and `%F` are used to get the filename and file type respectively.

For example, having this structure:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 edgar edgar   65 Nov 29 17:51 dirOne2Link -> /home/edgar/Documents/Gitlab/Linux_programming/testing/forums/one
lrwxrwxrwx 1 edgar edgar   65 Nov 29 17:54 fileTwo2Link -> /home/edgar/Documents/Gitlab/Linux_programming/testing/forums/two
drwxr-xr-x 2 edgar edgar 4096 Nov 29 17:50 one
-rwxr--r-- 1 edgar edgar  201 Nov 25 21:13 script
-rw-r--r-- 1 edgar edgar    0 Nov 29 17:50 two
```

Using the `find` command above I get:

```
./fileTwo2Link is a regular empty file
./dirOne2Link is a directory
```

**Solution 2**

You can also use  `find` without `-exec stat ...`:

```bash
find -type l  -printf "%p is a %Y\n"
```

With the command above I get:

```
./pipelink is a p
./fileTwo2Link is a f
./onemorebroken is a N
./dirOne2Link is a d
./broken is a N
```

Where `p` is a named pipe, `f` is a regular file, `N` is a non-existent file (e.g. the broken links), `d` is a directory.

Comment: Oooh! It finds the broken links also!

Comment: @BobaFit oh! That's true! I'll try to give a solution

Comment: @BobaFit are you using Linux? Because as far as I know `-xtype` is from `GNU find` so if you are using macOS maybe you will get an error.